# Using bfgminer on an Intel GPU on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gpu, ubuntu, bfgminer

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an i5 core and Ivy Bridge GPU. Using bfgminer I have successfully mined on my CPU, but my GPU is never recognized. I have installed OpenCl for Intel processors. I had my friend test his GPU using bfg on Win7 and his worked out-of-the-box. I would like to know how to use my Intel HD 4000 graphics for mining with bfg and Ubuntu.